# one's accusations

Tags: meaning

I have a question about the following sentence. 
"The detective tried to corroborate the woman's accusations."

In this case, which is correct?

a. She was accused. 
b. She accused someone.

Thank you.

Comment: Someone not too skillful with the language (and hence unlikely to use "corroborate") might be intending to say "she was accused", but by far the normal interpretation would be "she accused someone".

Comment: _The woman's accusations_ refers only to accusations that she made, not to accusations that were made against her (and it doesn't imply there were any accusations made against her, either).

Answer (score 2):

The woman made an [accusation](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/accusation):

ac·cu·sa·tion 
ˌakyəˈzāSH(ə)n/ 
noun
a charge or claim that someone has done something illegal or wrong.

The detective tried to [corroborate](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/corroborate) the woman's accusations.

**b**. She accused someone.

Comment: My pleasure, of course @Nori.